# How to read the changes in page (layout) in liferay DXP?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

Is there any service to read  changes in page( layout) in liferay DXP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Layout changes are stored in layout table in Liferay.

You can create Modal Listener that listen's event on a table.

It has methods like onAfterUpdate,onAfterCreate,onAfterRemove etc which might help you.

For details you can refer
https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/model-listeners